# recreating file from diff

Tags: unix, diff

How to create the original file from the diff,  I am having one of the files and deleted the other unknowingly. Is there any tool to convert the diff output to 'ed' diff (diff -e output) format or patch output format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you have:**

- the old file, and
- the diff

then this is simply a matter of applying the diff in the usual fashion:

```
patch the_file <the_diff
```

This is just the normal use case for applying a diff.

**If you have:**

- the new file, and
- the diff

then you can you can simply apply the patch in reverse using `patch`'s `-R` option:

```
patch -R the_file <the_diff
```

Comment: I applied patch -R command and created the original file. Then I tried to verify by taking a diff between the newly created old file and the existing new file. But the difference was different from the previous difference. But the patch was successful.

Answer (score 1):

That is exactly what `patch` is for!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use [`patch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch) to apply the diff to one of the original files.